FastAPI redirect [GET/Redirect/POST]
I need a way to redirect from a GET endpoint to a POST endpoint (with added data) in FastAPI, NOT the other way around, as most questions suggest.
I've tried returning:
Response(
    content=json.dumps(some_dict), 
    headers={'Location': url_to_post}, 
    status_code=status_code
)

I've tried status codes 302, 303 and 307 as suggested. Nothing seems to work - the resulting request always has GET method.
